# Find out what class a method belongs to (in Visual Studio or Resharper)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, resharper

If I'm looking at a method definition in Visual Studio (with Resharper) is there an easy way to find out what class it belongs to?  (As of now, I've resorted to a text search in the "up" direction for the string "class".)

Comment: Multiple classes in a single file? Hopefully you're referring to files marked "This code was created by a tool."

Answer (score 4):

The Resharper command [Go to containing declaration](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Navigation_and_Search__Go_to_Containing_Declaration.html) (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>) should do the trick

**Edit:**
Or if you have the [navigation bar](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/06/03/using-the-navigation-bar-vstiptool0026.aspx) at the top of the code window enabled, that should display the type name. But I have that turned off, since I use keyboard navigation and the bar itself slows down Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

You have files with more than one class in? That makes ponies sad...

Anyway, to actually answer, can't you just look at the navigation bar?

[image]

Comment: "That makes ponies sad..." +1

Answer (score 1):

The best (direct) way specific to your question is PHeiberg's answer.
But if you ask this question I guess you don't know the [File Structure](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Navigation_and_Search__Viewing_File_Structure.html) window that can be enabled by ReSharper->Windows->File Structure or by shortcut Ctrl+Alt+F.

[image]

With that window you see always where you are in your file.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from using ReSharper's File Structure and/or Go to Containing Declaration - options mentioned previously - there's also a tiny feature in ReSharper called [Quick Documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/coding_assistance.html#Quick_Documentation) that in my view is better suited for this kind of task since it shows you method info in-place, without forcing you to navigate anywhere from the method you're on. Ctrl+Q, Esc, and you're done. It works on all kinds of symbols (not limited to methods), both on declarations and on usages.

Answer (score 0):

For VS, right click on the function and select 'Go To Declaration'. (Ctrl + F12)

Comment: That doesn't work for me... are you sure you understand the question?  I am already at the method declaration (definition) and I want to see the *class* name

Comment: That takes you to where the method is declared, not to the type name of the containing type